# What is the easiest way to communicate with a device that the bus voltage is 1V, and the clock frequency is 30 Mhz?

Tags: circuit-analysis, fpga

What is the easiest way to communicate with a device that the bus voltage is 1V, and the clock frequency is 30 Mhz?  The data in the bus is bi-direction.

Since this is only part of my work, I want to find a easy way to realize this part, I need to spend more effort on other part.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I thought I can make it easily with a FPGA, but I did not find a 1V voltage I/O FPGA.

Comment: digital or analog? ... what communication protocol is being used? ... you could have used a level shifter with the FPGA

Comment: 1.8V logic is fairly common, but 1.0V is a super low voltage -- that will not be easy, since it leaves very little dynamic range headroom. If the interface is not a standard I2C or SPI but some unique bi-directional protocol, that makes the project harder because you will need to study the device's datasheet and timing diagrams to understand how to generate the required device driver. FPGA is natural if you are integrating with lots of digital logic, but a microcontroller is better for software integration. It depends on what's easiest for your system integration.

Comment: It is a digital signal.   It is similar to SPI but the data is bi-directional. I tried to make a voltage level conversion circuit plus a FPGA.  But It is delicate with poor reliability.

Comment: TI has level shifter of various kind e.g. sn74gtl2003.

Comment: This question is unanswerable - you need to define exactly what sort of communication protocol is in use, specific voltages, specific data patterns, and explain what you mean by "delicate"

Answer (score 0):

TI has a dual PECL differential line driver/receiver. Needs +5v, which is not what you want.

But turn that upside down, and use PNPs (diffpairs/tailcurrents) and a few hundred millivolt swings into 50Ohms to ground, and you have a very viable link.

Answer (score 0):

Kintex Ultrascale HP banks have a minimum Vcco of 0.950V.  Presumably you can run it as LVCMOS12 with Vcco of 1.0V.  However, if you don't have very many pins, it might make more sense to use some sort of a level translator, or perhaps run the FPGA at 1.2V and use a resistive voltage divider.  Alternatively, maybe something like this could work: https://www.ti.com/product/SN74TVC3010 .